# How to aggregate ngMessage of several field

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-messages

I am using Angular JS ngMessage directive for form validation and I would like to aggregate ngMessage alert of several fields. Basically, my form contains 3 inputs (day, month, year) and I want to display alert when the date is not valid (no matter if it is the day, the month or the year that is not valid). How can I do that? I have [plunkered](https://plnkr.co/edit/dzQzTOmkoqpiiQu0Apts?p=preview) my issue, here is how I use ngMessage directive :

```
<form name="messageAnimationForm">
  <label for="day">Day</label>
  <input ng-model="day" id="day" name="day" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="2" required class="ngMessageSample" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/"/> <br/><br/>
  <label for="month">Month</label>
  <input ng-model="month" id="month" name="month" ng-minlength="1" ng-maxlength="2" required class="ngMessageSample" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/"/><br/><br/>
  <label for="year">Year</label>
  <input ng-model="year" id="year" name="year" ng-minlength="4" ng-maxlength="4" required class="ngMessageSample" ng-pattern="/^\d+$/"/><br/><br/>

  <div>
    <div ng-messages="messageAnimationForm.day.$error" class="ngMessagesClass" ng-messages-multiple>
      <div ng-message="pattern" class="ngMessageClass">* This field is invalid, only numbers are allowed</div>
      <div ng-message="required" class="ngMessageClass">* Day is mandatory</div>
    </div>

    <div ng-messages="messageAnimationForm.month.$error" class="ngMessagesClass" ng-messages-multiple>
      <div ng-message="pattern" class="ngMessageClass">* This field is invalid, only numbers are allowed</div>
      <div ng-message="required" class="ngMessageClass">* Month is mandatory</div>
    </div>

    <div ng-messages="messageAnimationForm.year.$error" class="ngMessagesClass" ng-messages-multiple>
      <div ng-message="pattern" class="ngMessageClass">* This field is invalid, only numbers are allowed</div>
      <div ng-message="required" class="ngMessageClass">* Year is mandatory</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if your whole form as an error with `messageAnimationForm.$error`:

```
<div ng-messages="messageAnimationForm.$error" class="ngMessagesClass" ng-messages-multiple>
  <div ng-message="pattern" class="ngMessageClass">* A field is invalid, only numbers are allowed</div>
  <div ng-message="minlength" class="ngMessageClass">* It's mandatory at least 1 characters</div>
  <div ng-message="maxlength" class="ngMessageClass">* It's mandatory at most 2 characters</div>
</div>
```

[**Forked your Plunker here.**](https://plnkr.co/edit/7nM1P1WVcleL965KvU25?p=preview)

Answer (score 1):

Try adding a custom validator to one of the three fields and fire it manually from your controller (or add watches to the three date components to fire your validation function):

```
<form name="messageAnimationForm">
<div ng-messages="messageAnimationForm.year.$error" class="ngMessagesClass" ng-messages-multiple>
  <div ng-message="invalidDate" class="ngMessageClass">Date not valid</div>
</div>
</form>
```

then, in your controller you must check the validity of the date with your custom rules. If you want the message to be shown then you have to set the custom error to true (or to "false" to hide it):

```
$scope.messageAnimationForm.year.$error.invalidDate = checkIfYourDateIsValid();
```